# Is there any robovm bro-gen documentation

Tags: robovm

Is there any documentation on how to write YAML files for robovm bro-gen. I am trying to create bindings for a few ios libraries and I am forced to look at other YAML files as documentaion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scroll to the middle of the page here:

https://github.com/robovm/robovm-bro-gen

Also, it is useful to look into existing robopods at github. To make it work, you will also need to clone robovm main repository.

Comment: I am looking into it and existing yaml files for other robopods. I was hoping for nice descriptive example. Thank you.